# ARKit : how to find all planes hit by a hitTest?

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, arkit

I have a array of planes (non infinite planes => with finite dimensions) in a array:

```
Plane *plane = [[Plane alloc] initWithAnchor: (ARPlaneAnchor *)anchor];
[self.planes setObject:plane forKey:anchor.identifier];
```

(Plane object heritates from SCNNode and has a ARPlaneAnchor *anchor and a SCNPlane *planeGeometry properties)

How to find all the planes of the array planes which are hit by a hitTest at a point of the screen ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARKit : how to get a SCNNode hit by hitTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203065/arkit-how-to-get-a-scnnode-hit-by-hittest)

Comment: This question is more general. Because I am not satisfied by the answer given in the other question.

Comment: Your question itself doesn't make sense.  How could you touch more than 1 node at a time?  Are your users octopuses?

Comment: A hitTest can return all the items along the line where the user clicked in both SceneKit ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest )and ARKit ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest ). Note that I speak about a 3D scene. So, my question makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`categoryBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407994-categorybitmask) and set it for example to `3` (=11b). Then set the [`categoryBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestoption/1778148-categorybitmask) option in your hit test to 2 (=10b). That way only nodes where the second bit of the categroy is a 1 are returned.